# I am trying to make a caeser cipher in python (3.8), and there are constant errors coming up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to write a Ceaser cipher. As you can see below, an error comes up. However, from what I can tell, there should be no error.

The error is obvious happening at `translatedIndex = symbolIndex + key`, but that means either `symbolIndex` or `key` have the error. I am not sure which one it is, and I am not sure how I can fix this issue.

My code:

```
message = ''
mode = ''


print("Type what sort of function you would like. (NOTE: only lowercase, and the values of 'encrypt' and 'decrypt' are accepted)")

mode = input("What mode do you want: ")

message = input('What is the message you want to encrypt/decrypt: ')

key = input('What is the key: ')

SYMBOLS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !?.'


translated = ''

for symbol in message:
    # Note: Only symbols in the `SYMBOLS` string can be encrypted/decrypted.
    if symbol in SYMBOLS:
        symbolIndex = SYMBOLS.find(symbol)

        # Perform encryption/decryption:
        if mode == 'encrypt':
            translatedIndex = symbolIndex + key
        elif mode == 'decrypt':
            translatedIndex = symbolIndex - key


        # Handle wrap-around, if needed:
        if translatedIndex >= len(SYMBOLS):
            translatedIndex = translatedIndex - len(SYMBOLS)
        elif translatedIndex < 0:
            translatedIndex = translatedIndex + len(SYMBOLS)

        translated = translated + SYMBOLS[translatedIndex]
    else:
        # Append the symbol without encrypting/decrypting:
        translated = translated + symbol

print(translated)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mghaf/Desktop/Coding/coding/My codes (cypher)/caesarCipher.py", line 27, in <module>
    translatedIndex = symbolIndex + key
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Your error message just says you can't add an integer with a string. symbolIndex returns the index of that character and the key is a string value so naturally it doesn't make any sense. A few side notes, a Caesar Cipher shifts every value by the same constant value. If you're working with a key, it's a Vigenère Cipher. I would recommend looking into using a modulo by the length of SYMBOLS to simplify all of your wrap-around into a single line and just check out some examples of Caeser and Vigenere cipher implementations before you write your own.

Comment: @faris don't get fooled by the name of the variables, this is really just plain Caesar cipher... [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) requires multiple applications of Caesar cipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the fact you are trying to sum a `int` and a `str`.

In particular, the following line:

```
key = input('What is the key: ')
```

produces a `str`, even if the `str` contains numbers.
The simplest modification is to just cast the result of `input()` to `int`, e.g. replacing that line with:

```
key = int(input('What is the key: '))
```

---

As a side note, your code for handling wrapping around requires a small `key`. If your `key` is, say, `1000` you do need a different approach. Typically, this is solved using the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffarian if this answers your question, please consider marking the answer accepted (the check mark under the up/down vote arrows next to the answer). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers